# G1 gc log doesn't show clue for long gc pause

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a distributed cache application (memory bound, with networking I/O due to interaction with other nodes in the cluster) running in JVM 1.7.0_51 with G1 garbage collector. Here is the JVM configuration:

```
-server -Xms1G -Xmx3000M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50  -Xloggc:$HAZELCAST_HOME/logs/gclog.txt -verbose:gc
```

> At 2014-08-21T16:32:16.032, GC caused a long pause over 33 seconds (gc
>   log snippet as below): 2014-08-21T16:32:16.032-0700: 798408.606: Total
>   time for which application threads were stopped: 33.7010420 seconds

I dug into the gc logs (and also the application logs) and didn't see a clear clue why that 33-second long pause happened. Is there any way to have the G1 dump more details to show reason for the long pause (and the breakdown of the long pause for what event, e.g. xxxms for scanning RS, etc.).

I enclosed the gc logs for a few minutes. Do you see any issue in the GC log and any need for JVM gc tuning? 
Thanks a lot!

**GC logs**

```
2014-08-21T16:24:47.996-0700: 797960.570: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005740 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4957 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 535899K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 275 young (281600K), 6 survivors (6144K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16858K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe76ad8, 0x00000007fbe76c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:25:35.830-0700: 798008.405: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 15204352 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    1490920 bytes,    1490920 total
- age   2:    1041336 bytes,    2532256 total
- age   3:    1462192 bytes,    3994448 total
- age   4:     669528 bytes,    4663976 total
- age   5:     600560 bytes,    5264536 total
, 0.0387690 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 36.9 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798008405.0, Avg: 798008405.0, Max: 798008405.0, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.1, Avg: 5.4, Max: 5.7, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 10.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 6.3, Avg: 6.7, Max: 7.1, Diff: 0.8, Sum: 13.4]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 5, Avg: 14.0, Max: 23, Diff: 18, Sum: 28]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 8.5, Avg: 9.3, Max: 10.0, Diff: 1.5, Sum: 18.5]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 15.4, Avg: 15.4, Max: 15.5, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 30.9]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 36.8, Avg: 36.8, Max: 36.8, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 73.6]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798008441.8, Avg: 798008441.8, Max: 798008441.8, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 1.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.7 ms]
   [Eden: 269.0M(224.0M)->0.0B(606.0M) Survivors: 6144.0K->8192.0K Heap: 523.3M(1024.0M)->255.8M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4958 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 261979K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 8 young (8192K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16858K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe76ad8, 0x00000007fbe76c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2014-08-21T16:25:35.869-0700: 798008.444: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0395820 seconds
2014-08-21T16:25:47.806-0700: 798020.380: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004770 seconds
2014-08-21T16:26:43.565-0700: 798076.139: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004730 seconds
2014-08-21T16:26:47.960-0700: 798080.535: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004790 seconds
2014-08-21T16:27:47.180-0700: 798139.754: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006050 seconds
2014-08-21T16:27:47.474-0700: 798140.048: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004160 seconds
2014-08-21T16:28:13.565-0700: 798166.140: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006670 seconds
2014-08-21T16:28:43.565-0700: 798196.139: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004590 seconds
2014-08-21T16:28:47.880-0700: 798200.454: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004490 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:12.924-0700: 798225.499: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004600 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:12.925-0700: 798225.499: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001880 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:12.925-0700: 798225.499: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002230 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:12.928-0700: 798225.502: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0011150 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:12.932-0700: 798225.506: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0011190 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:13.565-0700: 798226.140: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005240 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4958 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 536411K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 276 young (282624K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16858K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe76ad8, 0x00000007fbe76c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:29:16.945-0700: 798229.519: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 14680064 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:    1751568 bytes,    1751568 total
- age   2:    1108160 bytes,    2859728 total
- age   3:     997960 bytes,    3857688 total
- age   4:    1449136 bytes,    5306824 total
- age   5:     662736 bytes,    5969560 total
- age   6:     595944 bytes,    6565504 total
, 0.0454900 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 43.6 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798229519.7, Avg: 798229519.7, Max: 798229519.7, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.0, Avg: 5.1, Max: 5.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 10.2]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 4.7, Avg: 4.8, Max: 4.9, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 9.7]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 7, Avg: 14.5, Max: 22, Diff: 15, Sum: 29]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 11.9, Avg: 12.0, Max: 12.0, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 23.9]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 21.6, Avg: 21.6, Max: 21.6, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 43.2]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 43.5, Avg: 43.5, Max: 43.5, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 87.1]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798229563.2, Avg: 798229563.2, Max: 798229563.2, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 1.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.7 ms]
   [Eden: 268.0M(210.0M)->0.0B(576.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->9216.0K Heap: 523.8M(1024.0M)->257.3M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4959 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 263515K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 9 young (9216K), 9 survivors (9216K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16858K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe76ad8, 0x00000007fbe76c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
2014-08-21T16:29:16.991-0700: 798229.565: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0462520 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:35.008-0700: 798247.583: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005370 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:35.098-0700: 798247.673: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003950 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:35.099-0700: 798247.673: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001400 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:43.566-0700: 798256.140: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006050 seconds
2014-08-21T16:29:47.791-0700: 798260.365: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004690 seconds
2014-08-21T16:30:33.232-0700: 798305.806: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0025060 seconds
2014-08-21T16:30:34.233-0700: 798306.807: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006220 seconds
2014-08-21T16:31:12.342-0700: 798344.917: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013470 seconds
2014-08-21T16:31:17.500-0700: 798350.074: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005640 seconds
2014-08-21T16:31:17.501-0700: 798350.076: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002760 seconds
2014-08-21T16:31:38.506-0700: 798371.080: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013400 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:16.032-0700: 798408.606: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 33.7010420 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:56.183-0700: 798448.758: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0120100 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:56.185-0700: 798448.759: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006060 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:56.201-0700: 798448.775: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014260 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:56.203-0700: 798448.777: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006110 seconds
2014-08-21T16:32:56.204-0700: 798448.778: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004730 seconds
2014-08-21T16:33:16.026-0700: 798468.601: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0021260 seconds
2014-08-21T16:33:50.414-0700: 798502.988: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014210 seconds
2014-08-21T16:34:47.479-0700: 798560.054: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015890 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4959 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 657755K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 394 young (403456K), 9 survivors (9216K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:35:19.033-0700: 798591.607: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 5767168 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
- age   1:    2254608 bytes,    2254608 total
- age   2:    1409360 bytes,    3663968 total
- age   3:    1058280 bytes,    4722248 total
- age   4:     987544 bytes,    5709792 total
- age   5:    1435864 bytes,    7145656 total
- age   6:     658560 bytes,    7804216 total
- age   7:     593592 bytes,    8397808 total
, 0.0751810 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 71.2 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798591607.4, Avg: 798591607.4, Max: 798591607.4, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 6.1, Avg: 6.4, Max: 6.8, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 12.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 8.3, Avg: 8.8, Max: 9.3, Diff: 0.9, Sum: 17.6]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 11, Avg: 16.0, Max: 21, Diff: 10, Sum: 32]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 13.6, Avg: 13.7, Max: 13.9, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 27.4]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 41.9, Avg: 41.9, Max: 41.9, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 83.8]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.2]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 71.0, Avg: 71.0, Max: 71.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 142.0]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798591678.4, Avg: 798591678.4, Max: 798591678.4, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.8 ms]
   [Other: 3.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 2.4 ms]
   [Eden: 385.0M(74.0M)->0.0B(73.0M) Survivors: 9216.0K->8192.0K Heap: 642.3M(1024.0M)->258.4M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4960 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 264569K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 8 young (8192K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2014-08-21T16:35:19.108-0700: 798591.682: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0762870 seconds
2014-08-21T16:35:47.699-0700: 798620.273: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0010630 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4960 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 339321K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 81 young (82944K), 8 survivors (8192K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:36:30.675-0700: 798663.249: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 5767168 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 15)
- age   1:    2632352 bytes,    2632352 total
- age   2:    1093712 bytes,    3726064 total
- age   3:    1028456 bytes,    4754520 total
- age   4:    1044688 bytes,    5799208 total
- age   5:     977400 bytes,    6776608 total
, 0.0444430 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 43.2 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798663249.6, Avg: 798663249.6, Max: 798663249.7, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.0, Avg: 5.4, Max: 5.8, Diff: 0.8, Sum: 10.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 5.8, Avg: 6.3, Max: 6.7, Diff: 0.9, Sum: 12.5]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 11, Avg: 13.0, Max: 15, Diff: 4, Sum: 26]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 11.1, Avg: 11.1, Max: 11.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 22.2]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 20.3, Avg: 20.3, Max: 20.4, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 40.7]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 43.2, Avg: 43.2, Max: 43.2, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 86.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798663292.8, Avg: 798663292.8, Max: 798663292.8, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
   [Other: 1.1 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.5 ms]
   [Eden: 73.0M(73.0M)->0.0B(100.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->6144.0K Heap: 331.4M(1024.0M)->259.0M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4961 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 265216K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 6 young (6144K), 6 survivors (6144K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-08-21T16:36:30.720-0700: 798663.294: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0453210 seconds
2014-08-21T16:36:47.997-0700: 798680.572: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007030 seconds
2014-08-21T16:37:47.460-0700: 798740.034: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007800 seconds
2014-08-21T16:37:48.932-0700: 798741.506: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006490 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4961 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 367616K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 106 young (108544K), 6 survivors (6144K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:38:05.883-0700: 798758.457: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 7340032 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:     535816 bytes,     535816 total
- age   2:    2490064 bytes,    3025880 total
- age   3:    1060536 bytes,    4086416 total
- age   4:    1024088 bytes,    5110504 total
, 0.0365490 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 35.5 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798758457.2, Avg: 798758457.2, Max: 798758457.3, Diff: 0.0]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.2, Avg: 6.4, Max: 7.6, Diff: 2.4, Sum: 12.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 5.2, Avg: 6.5, Max: 7.7, Diff: 2.4, Sum: 12.9]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 12.0, Max: 24, Diff: 24, Sum: 24]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 8.6, Avg: 8.7, Max: 8.8, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 17.4]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 13.7, Avg: 13.8, Max: 13.9, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 27.7]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 35.4, Avg: 35.4, Max: 35.4, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 70.8]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798758492.6, Avg: 798758492.6, Max: 798758492.6, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
   [Other: 0.9 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.1 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.5 ms]
   [Eden: 100.0M(100.0M)->0.0B(178.0M) Survivors: 6144.0K->7168.0K Heap: 359.0M(1024.0M)->259.5M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4962 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 265728K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 7 young (7168K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-08-21T16:38:05.920-0700: 798758.494: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0375420 seconds
2014-08-21T16:38:26.099-0700: 798778.673: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0010220 seconds
2014-08-21T16:38:47.342-0700: 798799.916: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0036430 seconds
2014-08-21T16:39:47.317-0700: 798859.892: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008300 seconds
2014-08-21T16:39:56.099-0700: 798868.674: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006290 seconds
2014-08-21T16:40:47.760-0700: 798920.334: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006050 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=4962 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 448000K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 185 young (189440K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
2014-08-21T16:41:06.971-0700: 798939.546: [GC pause (young)
Desired survivor size 12582912 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:     660960 bytes,     660960 total
- age   2:     447312 bytes,    1108272 total
- age   3:    2380256 bytes,    3488528 total
- age   4:    1043336 bytes,    4531864 total
- age   5:    1019096 bytes,    5550960 total
, 0.0459440 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 43.9 ms, GC Workers: 2]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 798939545.8, Avg: 798939545.8, Max: 798939545.9, Diff: 0.1]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 6.4, Avg: 6.4, Max: 6.4, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 12.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 7.9, Avg: 9.3, Max: 10.6, Diff: 2.7, Sum: 18.5]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 12, Avg: 14.0, Max: 16, Diff: 4, Sum: 28]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 7.5, Avg: 8.8, Max: 10.2, Diff: 2.8, Sum: 17.7]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 19.2, Avg: 19.3, Max: 19.3, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 38.5]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 43.7, Avg: 43.8, Max: 43.8, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 87.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 798939589.6, Avg: 798939589.6, Max: 798939589.6, Diff: 0.0]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 1.4 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.2 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.7 ms]
   [Eden: 178.0M(178.0M)->0.0B(193.0M) Survivors: 7168.0K->7168.0K Heap: 437.5M(1024.0M)->259.5M(1024.0M)]
Heap after GC invocations=4963 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 1048576K, used 265728K [0x000000073f600000, 0x000000077f600000, 0x00000007fae00000)
  region size 1024K, 7 young (7168K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 compacting perm gen  total 20480K, used 16898K [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fc200000, 0x0000000800000000)
   the space 20480K,  82% used [0x00000007fae00000, 0x00000007fbe80ab0, 0x00000007fbe80c00, 0x00000007fc200000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
 [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
2014-08-21T16:41:07.018-0700: 798939.592: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0471700 seconds
2014-08-21T16:41:47.416-0700: 798979.990: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006110 seconds
2014-08-21T16:42:26.100-0700: 799018.674: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008380 seconds
2014-08-21T16:42:47.463-0700: 799040.037: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008070 seconds
2014-08-21T16:43:26.100-0700: 799078.675: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0009130 seconds
2014-08-21T16:43:47.648-0700: 799100.222: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006330 seconds
2014-08-21T16:43:48.700-0700: 799101.274: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006050 seconds
2014-08-21T16:44:18.539-0700: 799131.113: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006640 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to garbage collection. According to the log the pause has happened outside GC cycle.

`Total time for which application threads were stopped` message is printed after every safepoint. Extremely long safepoint time can be typically seen due to OS freezes. This may happen because of intensive disk I/O, or when the system starts swapping, or when another high-priority process takes all CPU time. To find out the reason examine your OS performance counters.

Comment: Do you know how to print out the details of/reason for "Total time for which application threads were stopped" in G1 gc log? I tried using XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics, but it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisaLiu Add `-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` along with `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics`. But that won't say much anyway, because the common reason is "the operating system is busy". That's why I suggest you to watch OS counters: CPU, RAM, Swap, I/O queue etc.